# IntelliJ run Scalatest using $MODULE_WORKING_DIR$?

Tags: intellij-idea, scalatest

I have a multi-project SBT config that I've imported into IntelliJ (2019.3). I want each project (module) to run Scalatests from its own directory instead of the multi-project root directory. I went to Run -> Edit Configurations -> Templates -> ScalaTest and set Working directory to $MODULE_WORKING_DIR$, but I get the following error:

"Cannot start process, the working directory '$MODULE_WORKING_DIR$' does not exist".

I am able to use the $MODULE_WORKING_DIR$ macro in my normal run configurations, but it doesn't work in ScalaTest. Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is there a different way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Could you please try removing target dir and check, if it helps?

Comment: There's no "target directory" field, but there is "Working directory". If I remove that, it tries to use the root directory of the multi-project, and the tests fail. What I want is for each project in my multi-project config to use its own directory as the working directory when I run tests.